# Prove that $\frac{g(x)}{\ln(1+x)}$ is integrable over $[0,1].$

Tags: integration, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

> **Question**: Let $f$ be a measurable function on $[0,1]$ such that 
>   $$g(x) = |f(x)| \ln(1+x)$$
>   is Lebsegue integrable over $[0,1].$
>   Prove that $f$ is Lebesgue integrable over $[0,1]$

So the question is asking us to show that 
$$\int_0^1 |f(x)|\, dx = \int_0^1 \frac{|g(x)|}{\ln(1+x)}dx$$
is finite.

However, I think that the question is not correct. 
Clearly $g(x) = 1$ is Lebesgue integrable over $[0,1],$ as 
$$\int_0^1 |g(x)| \, dx = 1,$$ 
but
$$\int_0^1 \frac{1}{\ln(1+x)}dx,$$
based on [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=int_0%5E1%20%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7Bln(1%2Bx)%7D%20dx), is not finite.
So $f$ is not Lebesgue integrable over $[0,1].$

Is my reasoning correct?

Comment: Yes, it's correct.

Comment: 'It' refers to my reasoning or the question?

Comment: Your reasoning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your reasoning is correct: intuitively, it could be thanks to the fact that $\ln(1+x)$ goes to $0$ as $x$ goes to zero that $g$ is integrable while $f$ alone is not.

The example $f\colon x\mapsto 1/\ln(1+x)$ shows this. It is indeed true that $\int_0^1 \frac{1}{\ln(1+x)}\mathrm dx$ is divergent but this requires a mathematical justification. This is due to the fact that $\lim_{x\to 0}\ln(1+x)/x=1$ and the divergence of $\int_0^1 \frac{1}{x}\mathrm dx$.